# Zakamouline Optimal Hedging of Options with Transaction Costs

Tags: options, delta-hedging

I've read that the Zakamouline method suggests the best optimal hedging of options when taking transaction costs into account. I've read the article but am having difficulty understanding it well enough to put it into practice. Does anyone know what the equation would look like in Excel?